# LabVIEW and OOP through .NET assembly

Tags: labview

I would like to reuse an instance created with the constructor node. Say once I create an instance of Camera as seen in the diagram below, how do I reuse it other places ? For variables and buttons I know that I can create a local variable or a reference and update, but I can't find a way to reuse instances. Could anyone please shed some light ?

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The cyan wire coming out of the constructor node is a reference to an object. You can fork that wire to anywhere else in your program that you want to use it. Your Event Structure is probably inside a While Loop. It's likely that you want to create a shift register on the border of the loop and wire the object reference wire to the right-hand shift register so you can reuse the reference in other frames on later events. Here's an image to explain...

[image: Your program with shift registers added]

Comment: Thank you @srm. If I implement the way you suggested then where do I instantiate a Camera object ?

Comment: If you know that you're going to need it unconditionally in the loop, I'd do it before the loop starts and wire the reference into the outside left shift register. If you only need it if a certain event occurs, leave it right where it is -- if it doesn't already exist, that "isOpen" will error out and you'll go into the False case and create it. If it does exist, just add an extra case structure around the constructor node to not construct it if it you did *not* get an error from the isOpen call.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the reference to the instance. Wire a reference to an indicator from the camera constructor node and then use that reference via local variables the same way as you would normally do.

Comment: Thank you @D.J. Klomp. Unless I create a shift register I can't wire a reference and I can't create a local variable.